# Getting error while migrating to Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, swift3

I am getting error while migrating to Swift 3. Below is the code in which error comes.

```
func getProfileFieldValue(_ formFields:NSMutableArray,keyValue:String) -> String {
    for key in formFields{
        if keyValue == key["name"] as! String{
            return key["value"] as! String
        }

    }
    return ""
}
```

[image]

Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

`NSMutableArray` does not provide any type information, use native Swift array

```
func getProfileFieldValue(_ formFields:[[String:Any]], keyValue: String) -> String {
    for key in formFields {
        if let value = key["name"] as? String, value == keyValue {
            return key["value"] as! String
        }

    }
    return ""
}
```

or if the dictionaries contain only `String` values

```
func getProfileFieldValue(_ formFields:[[String:String]], keyValue: String) -> String {
    for key in formFields {
        if let value = key["name"], value == keyValue {
            return key["value"]!
        }

    }
    return ""
}
```

Or still *swiftier*

```
func getProfileFieldValue(_ formFields:[[String:Any]], keyValue: String) -> String {
    if let profileField = formFields.first(where { $0["name"] as? String == keyValue }) {
        return profileField["value"] as! String
    }
    return ""
}
```

Finally the *waterproof-will-never-crash* version:

```
func getProfileFieldValue(_ formFields:[[String:Any]], keyValue: String) -> String {
    guard let profileField = formFields.first(where: { $0["name"] as? String == keyValue }),
        let value = profileField["value"] as? String else { return "" }
    return value
}
```

Comment: If possible use the second solution. The strong type system encourages the developer to be as type specific as possible.

Comment: Why not returning value "instead" of "key["value"]!"? Removing some force unwrapping is always a good choice :)

Comment: Yes, you are right but value is of mixed type. So I need to use Anyobject.

Comment: Why does this code force unwrap the return value? There is no prior check to ensure that the `key` dictionary actually contains a value for the key `"value"` (that's some confusing naming conventions).

Comment: @rmaddy I don't know the data source. The code in the question implies that there is always a string value for key `value` if there is a key `name`. Don't shoot the messenger ;-).

Comment: @vadian Perhaps but how many questions get posted every day asking about everyone's favorite "forced unwrapping" error because the person's code implied a value wasn't nil when it actually was? Why safely unwrap for the `"name"` key but not the `"value"` key?

Comment: @rmaddy I added the safe version.

Answer (score 2):

`NSMutableArray` does not provide type information, so you'll need to cast the array prior to the for loop

```
let array = NSMutableArray(array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
let keyValue = 3

for item in array as! [Int]
{
    if keyValue == item
    {}
}
```

Comment: A better solution is to avoid using `NSMutableArray` at all.

Comment: @rmaddy Agreed - always better to use the modern swift classes, when possible